# Add user-defined module into Database Engine to pre-processing T-SQL queries

Tags: sql-server

I write a module to translate 1 sql query into another query. When users send sql queries to DB-Engine, then DB-Engine will firstly forward these queries to my defined-module before processing sql syntax.

How can I integrate my-defined module to DB-Engine of SQL Server?

Comment: Are the callers to be aware or must this be transparent?

Comment: In fact, I want to give transparently access for applications to distributed data on 2 database servers

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect queries for certain data to different tables using a partitioned view:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188299(v=SQL.105).aspx

In a nutshell, you tell the server some rules as to which values reside in which tables (usually based on primary or foreign key ranges for example). When you query using the partition field, the database can direct your query to the correct remote table. But you can still do queries over all the tables just as if they were held locally (except more slowly).

Comment: THank you for your answer. It partitions a table horizontally, however I want to slice table vertically, but seemly SQL server not support?

Comment: @xuantrang_2910, that's even easier. Just create a linked server, and make a view onto the remote table. Then create a view containing the fields from both tables you want.